# C++ STL map keys and values not working properly

Tags: c++, networking, dictionary, stl, client-server

I develop one program in which i am accepting the keys and values from system itself for stl map.

I want to accomplish following task.
my key ranges from 0 to 1000.
Before inserting values to key i have to check whether there is same key in map.
if yes i have to increase key by 1 and assign values to that key.
I am trying in following way.But i am not succeed.

```
map<int, Values> items;

Values connection (inet_ntoa(Clientaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(Clientaddr.sin_port),inet_ntoa(Servaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(Servaddr.sin_port));

for(unsigned int key=0;key<=1000;key++)
{
map<int,Values>::const_iterator itemsIterator=items.find(key);

if(itemsIterator==items.end())
{
items.insert(pair<int, Values> (key, connection));
}
else
{
cout<<"already exist";
key++;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you intend to assign the same connection to all unused keys? If not, you need to add a `break;` statement after the insertion. You also don't want the `key++` line since `key` will already be incremented in the next pass of your `for` loop.

Comment: What if `key + 1` also already exists?

Comment: I want to assign one connection to one unused key only.

Comment: Why not pick `items.rend()->first + 1` as the key?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're pairing the connection with all unused keys. You're also doing something I don't quite understand where you're doubly-incrementing `key` if it exists in the map. This should fix both issues:

```
map<int, Values> items;

Values connection (inet_ntoa(Clientaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(Clientaddr.sin_port),inet_ntoa(Servaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(Servaddr.sin_port));

for(unsigned int key=0;key<=1000;key++)
{
  map<int,Values>::const_iterator itemsIterator=items.find(key); //try to find the key in the map

  if(itemsIterator==items.end()) //if the key doesn't currently exist in the map
  {
    items.insert(pair<int, Values> (key, connection)); //add it to the map with the connection
    break; //and exit the loop
  }
  else //the key already exists, try the next one in the next pass of the for loop
  {
    cout<<"already exist";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see four defects in the code snippet you presented.

First of all you defined map as having key_type `int` while in the loop you use the type of key `unsigned int`. Though it is not an error but makes the code less clear. So you should decide whether key_type will be `int`or `unsigned int` In the loop it is better to specify `key_type` instead of explicit specifying some integral type.

So I would write the control statement of loop as

```
for ( std::map<int, Values>::key_type key = 0; key <= 1000; key++ )
```

Also you increase key twice in the loop if it is already present in the map.

```
for(unsigned int key=0;key<=1000;key++)
{
//...
else
{
cout<<"already exist";
key++;
}
}
```

It is increased in the control statement itself and in the compound statement of the else.

The third defect is that you do not call function connection in statement

```
items.insert(pair<int, Values> (key, connection));
```

In this statement expression `connection` has type of pointer to function. I think that you have to call the function that to get value calculated by the function.

And the fourth defect is incorrect syntax of statement

```
Values connection (inet_ntoa(Clientaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(Clientaddr.sin_port),inet_ntoa(Servaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(Servaddr.sin_port));
```

It is not clear whether it is a function call or a function declaration.

So I would rewrite the code snippet as

```
std::map<int, Values> items;

for( std::map<int, Values>::key_type key = 0; key <= 1000; key++ )
{
    std::map<int, Values>::const_iterator itemsIterator = items.find( key );

   if( itemsIterator == items.end() )
   {
      items.insert( pair<int, Values>( key,  connection( /*arguments of the function*/ ) ) );
   }
   else
   {
      cout << key << " already exists";
   }
}
```